# What is this device?

Tags: isp

I'm trying to create a map from a network based on some photos of a rack.

And I need to know what is this device, apparently it's the entry point for one of the ISPs.

[image]

I'm not a network expert

Comment: It looks like a PoE injector. Is there a model number on it.

Comment: With the warning on it, likely a proprietary, passive power injector.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: This question is only soliciting opinion-based answers, so it is off-topic for that. Let us know if you find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like a PoE injector.  The top port looks like the network port (the switch) and the left port looks like it's for the device, maybe like an outdoor wireless AP that requires more-than-standard power.  Injectors sometimes have that warning telling you not to connect the PoE-side into a PC or a switch.

Answer (score 0):

What else is wired to it? If a ground wire then likely a surge-protector, if a power supply then POE adapter, if a VGA or audio it is a cat 5 extender